# Javascript and CSS (and other languages) equivalents of "SQLZoo", "RegexOne" and "TryRuby"

Tags: javascript, css

I've found the sites SQLZoo, RegexOne, and TryRuby to be incredibly helpful in understanding basics of those technologies. Are there any similar resources for javascript and CSS? (i.e. online interactive learn-by-doing, with immediate feedback type of thing). Are there any similar resources for other languages?  Particularly HTML, PHP, Perl, Python or even Java and the C languages.

Comment: How about your browser? There's even a debugger, and you can make live changes to most everything.

Comment: Yea that's a good idea.. browser debugger is really useful when I have a specific idea I want to test out, but I'm also looking for resources that involve a little more guidance in addition to the immediate feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for CSS, HTML, and JavaScript. You are given a spot for CSS, HTML, and JavaScript and then an output window to see your results. It also has the ability to check your code for errors and clean up formatting.

For PHP, give [phptester](http://phptester.net/) a try.

I have yet to see anything for the other languages, but if anyone else can find them, they should add them to this post.

Comment: Thanks for the links! I love jsFiddle. Hadn't heard of phptester before but looks useful. Like I mentioned above though, I'm also looking for resources that involve a little more guided learning in addition to providing a way to test out code.